# curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer while download repo

Tags: android, repository

When I run this command:

```
curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

into the terminal to download repo, it fails with the following error:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer while download repo
```

Why and how to finally succeed in downloading repo (to get the Android sources)?

Comment: have you add USER_AGENT ID to your CURL?

Answer (score 0):

That command works just fine here. Check your network settings. What operating system are you running on? Have you verified that you have internet connectivity?

Comment: It would have been better to ask for more information by using the comment field, not by opening a response.

Comment: Thank you all! To Zygote: My os is ubuntu 13.10, and the network worked fine, I am not sure that the reason is because I am in China.